# IP on website differing from IP in aws instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, web-hosting

I'm doing work on a group aws project where I am not the original creator of the instances. I'm asked to fix a bug however the instances that are running do not link to the domain in question. (with either their elastic ip or private ip).

When i stop the instances in question the webpage does nothing and is unaffected.

This makes me think that I was given incorrect credentials however I'm able to very with hosting records the site is hosted indeed on aws and in the same region listed on the backend. Not sure what is going on here, Is there another layer of IP masking going on? and why doesn't the website go down when i stop the instance.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The frontend might be a static one created in angular ,react or HTML , hence once you stop the server only the backend goes down not the whole website if you are pointing to the current ec2 instance

To find out the correct ec2 instance goto the website

> > do a right click >> click on networks tab >> goto Xhr requests
> > Make an API call and check the request URL

Now using any DNS checker check the IP of the request domain , and you will find the IP website is pointing to

Comment: I essentially did this with a ping request and they do not match up. However the dns records point to aws as well.